# How to use mysql insted of mysqli in PHP

Tags: php, wamp

I have the latest version of wamp server , Can i use mysql_ commands if i downgraded wamp ? I have to study for a exam which all the php methods are not in mysqli format. 
 Please help !

Comment: Why would you be tested on a deprecated feature?

Comment: If your exam is requiring `mysql_*` you really need a new university.

Comment: Not entirely @mistermartin

Comment: Please try to help! :) yeh i know that , What to do @ceejayoz

Comment: There are still plenty of out of date sites with mysql_ examples. There are still plenty of old questions on here with mysql_ example. Calm down, breathe, and search.

Comment: Thank you :) i'll search ^_^

Comment: I think we all agree that you should not use `mysql_*` functions. As pointed out, they were deprecated in PHP version 5.5 and removed in PHP version 7. So, if you cannot use `mysql_*` functions you're obviously using PHP 7. A quick look at the [site](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) suggest that you are using Wampserver version 3. This bundles PHP versions 5.6 and 7. So it should be possible to downgrade to 5.6, in which these deprecated functions will still be available. Just bear in mind that you should never use them in practice. And learn about PHP's PDO library, and prepared statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

The mysql_* functions have long been deprecated, and were finally
removed in PHP 7. The mysqli_* functions are quite similar and it should be pretty easy to 'upgrade' a piece of code to use mysqli, even if you don't use the extra features, like bind parameters.

But for a course, even a small difference may cause a lot of confusement, so if you really want to do this particular exam, you could downgrade to a
version prior to PHP 7.0.

The [WampServer website](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) still refers to older downloads on SourceForge. You can download [WampServer 2 with PHP 5.5](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/). That should work.

You might consider [using a virtual machine](http://www.itworld.com/article/2981582/virtualization/microsoft-tells-developers-download-our-free-virtual-machines.html) to install it on, if you also want to keep your currently installed latest version.

But if you have any choice, choose another exam or course, because this one is very outdated.

If you were going to learn a more modern database API, I'd choose PDO. It's just more modern, more flexible and feels less tied to MySQL as its only data source. So in my personal opinion you'd use mysqli to quickly upgrade from mysql, but use PDO for new developments, although opinions on this may vary. :)

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: The latest version of [WAMPServer 3.0.4](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/files/install/wampserver3.0.4_x86_apache2.4.18_mysql5.7.11_php5.6.19-7.0.4.exe) comes with PHP5.6 **and** PHP7. The PHP5.6 will still contain the `mysql_` API. __Remember in WAMPServer you can switch PHP versions in and out with the click of a menu

Answer (score 0):

There is very little difference between using mysql_* and mysqli_* but if you still want to use mysql_* you can install older version of XAMPP from here .

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.8.0/

Comment: And with WAMPServer you can have multiple versions of PHP loaded and switch between them at the click of a menu. PHP7 and PHP5.6 and PHP5.5 and PHP5.4 etc etc

Answer (score 0):

Why you still wants to use `mysql_` or `mysqli_` extension while the `PHP Developers` are moving to `PDO` instead of these old extensions because of less security of these extensions.

I think you should move to `PDO` to **secure and less coded your website** instead of **making vulnerable and insecure your website**.

But the question arises here of your university. So, you should try to move your class and class teacher to the `PDO` because the extension `mysql_` has been remove and depreciated in `PHP 7`.

After all, if you still wants to use `mysql_` extension then you should download `XAMPP` server to run it.